# onBackPressed calls onResume again

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app that registers the device with google GCM for push notifications. It works fine you can register the phone for notifications and once registered it displays a website in a webview and is ready for notifications.

The problem is when the mainActivity screen is loaded, the website is shown ok, but if he user clicks the back key it calls onResume again. I've tried calling

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

.

from the calling activity in a bid to clear the stack and hopefully exit the app. This is what i want, when the back key is pressed the app exits. I've also tried System.exit(0), which i know you are not supposed to do.

Why does the onResume run from a backkey press?

This is the activity that the onResume keeps running, following that is how i call that class.

thanks inadvance matt.

```
import static com.bmi.bmitestapp.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;
import static com.bmi.bmitestapp.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
import static com.bmi.bmitestapp.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // label to display gcm messages
    TextView lblMessage;

    // Asyntask
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    public static String name;
    public static String email;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        email = i.getStringExtra("email");     

        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        // Check if regid already presents
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }      //end of oncreate

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();






    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "in onResume in mainactivity");

    }



}
```

.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("name", "hardcoded client name");
                i.putExtra("email", "hardcoded email");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved]
From the calling activity i changed setFlags to

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```